# Dropzone JS: How to get URLs of each image to pass as separate AJAX request after uploading process?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, file-upload, dropzone.js

I'm going off of Dropzone.js resources provided by: http://www.dropzonejs.com/

**What I'm trying to do** - After uploading the image(s) and filling out all inputs, to get the link for each image that was uploaded in this session, to be passed into an AJAX request URL as a POST type.

My HTML:

```
<div id="myForm">
    <input type="text" id="form-name" placeholder="Name">
    <input type="text" id="form-email" placeholder="Email">

    <form action="/upload-target" class="dropzone" id="myDropZone"></form>

    <button id="submit-info">submit</button>
</div>
```

My JS:

```
<script>  
    $("div#myDropzone").dropzone({ url: "/upload.php" },
        function() {
            console.log("Hello");
        });
</script>
```

The images are uploaded to a directory mentioned in the PHP code below, but I have a problem with the above script, where the output in the console doesn't even print. `Hello` doesn't show in the console when anything is uploaded.

My `upload.php`:

```
<?php
    $ds          = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

    $storeFolder = 'img/uploads';

    if (!empty($_FILES)) {

        $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];          

        $targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . $ds. $storeFolder . $ds;

        $targetFile =  $targetPath. $_FILES['file']['name'];

        move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);

    }
?>
```

> Just to explain the above code, once an image(s) is
>   selected/drag-and-dorpped, `upload.php` uploads the images to
>   http://example.com/img/uploads/ folder.

**Here's where I need help:**

I am trying for when clicking the button with id `submit-info`, passing each image I've just uploaded as a string to the AJAX request:

```
<script>
    $('#submit-info').click(function() {
        var str = "name=" + $('#form-name').val()
                + "&email=" + $('#form-email').val()
                + "&images=" + /* what to put here */;

        console.log(str);

        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "sendEmail.php",
            data: str,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (confirmation) {
                // some code here dealing with after the email is sent like hiding the form
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
var files = '';

if (Dropzone.forElement("#my-dropzone").files.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i<Dropzone.forElement("#my-dropzone").files.length; i++) {
        if (i === (Dropzone.forElement("#my-dropzone").files.length - 1) ) {
            files += Dropzone.forElement("#my-dropzone").files[i].name;
        }
        else {
            files += Dropzone.forElement("#my-dropzone").files[i].name + '~';
        }
    }
}
```

The above code should be placed inside of the `$('#submit-info').click(function() { ...` so that once the submit button is clicked, we set an empty string, check if there are any files that were uploaded, and concatenate them if they exist.

For this example, the files are being separated by `~` characters. So once the string is passed through, you can declare your `str` variable like so:

```
$('#submit-info').click(function() {
    var str = "name=" + $('#form-name').val()
            + "&email=" + $('#form-email').val()
            + "&images=" + files;
```

Comment: This did it! Thanks :)